# How to reconstruct a C struct given memory content?

Tags: c, struct, gdb

Given some memory content (e.g. from gdb) I would like to reconstruct the content of a C struct. The `struct` is defined as follows (see [man semop](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop)):

```
unsigned short sem_num;  /* semaphore number */
short          sem_op;   /* semaphore operation */
short          sem_flg;  /* operation flags */
```

and the memory content (as indicated by the address of the struct using a debugger) is as follows:

```
00000000  00 00 ff ff 00 10 78 bd  21 0a 8c c8 24 0a c4 95  |......x.!...$...|
00000010  5e 09 d0 69 22 08 18 78  c9 bf ed f4 28 08 00 00  |^..i"..x....(...|
00000020  00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00  |................|
```

What are the values of `sem_num`, `sem_op` and `sem_flag`? Is it safe to assume that the first variable uses one byte, while the other two use two bytes each? Can I then do just the following mapping?

```
sem_num = 00
sem_op  = 00 ff
sem_flg = ff 00
```

Comment: Why would an `unsigned short` use one byte, and a `short` use two bytes?

Comment: Did you try a memcpy into the struct?

Comment: Also consider struct padding, and endianness.

Comment: @all: I cannot access the original code. I only have the output of gdb, and in my case, I need to know how `semop` was called.

Comment: You don't need to access the original code to memcpy into the struct. Simply redefine the struct in your test code, make a byte array with the correct bytes, memcpy it over, then look at the values in the struct. If you're on the same platform and compiler, this should work well.

Comment: depending on the architecture and the compiler configuration, the interpretation can change

Comment: @Dirk: You mean that I should write essentially a one-line C test code, compile and run it, and check how the memory looks in it, and then reverse-engineer the content for the actual case?

Comment: @Alex, I'd assume little and say 
`sem_num = 0x0000 (2 bytes), sem_op = 0xffff(ie -1) and sem_flg = 0x0010`. If you happen to know what value was defined after this in the program you can validate the subsequent values (0x210a .. ) against this.

Comment: Can you use `gdb` on the actual program? If the program has symbols, you can type `print *(struct sembuf *)0xtheaddress`.

Comment: @Mark: The program does not have symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of Dark Falcon, the following code seems to do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

int
main (void)
{
  struct sembuf my_sembuf[1]= {
    {0,-1,16*256}
  };

  unsigned char data[sizeof my_sembuf];
  size_t i;
  memcpy(data, &my_sembuf, sizeof my_sembuf);
  for (i=0; i < sizeof my_sembuf; ++i)
    printf("%02x\n", data[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

The include ensure the `semop` structure is already defined, which need to be filled and compared with the memory dump. It turns out, the content of the semop structure must be the following:

```
unsigned short sem_num = 0;
short          sem_op  = -1;
short          sem_flg = 16*256; /* Corresponding to the flag SEM_UNDO */
```